# Disambiguate non-const and const access methods (Pybind11)

Tags: c++, pybind11

I am trying to wrap some C++ class using Pybind11.
The class (Alpha) two getters, one returning a const reference to a member `force_` the other one returning a non-const reference.

```
struct Dummy {
  double x{3.3};
};

class Alpha {

 const Dummy& force() const {return force_;}
 Dummy& force() {return force_;}
 
 private:
   Dummy force_;
};
```

I initially tried using the  `py::return_value_policy` however this way, it seems like i didn't correctly disambiguate between the two versions of function `force()` as I am getting
`note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:` and `couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Func’`

```
py::class_<Alpha>(m, "Alpha")
      .def(py::init())
      .def("force", &Alpha::force, "returns reference", py::return_value_policy::reference_internal)
      .def("force", &Alpha::force, "returns copy", py::return_value_policy::copy);
}
```

Am I heading in a completely wrong direction? I do not really want do alter the C++ side of the code. A side question would be: How could I write `&Alpha::force` unambiguously to either mean the const or non-const version.

Comment: is `Func` the type of the second argument to `def`? I am asking because `&Alpha::force` cannot work like that, but I know too little about pybind to write a complete answer

Comment: Yes it is! The documentation states that ``Func``
        can be a plain C++ function, a function pointer, or a lambda function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know pybind, but I suppose `Func` is the type that `def` tries to deduce from its second parameter. The issue is that you cannot get a function pointer to an overload set. You can only get a function pointer to a single function.

> The documentation states that Func can be a plain C++ function, a function pointer, or a lambda function

Ok, but it cannot be a whole set of overloads!

Thats why with your class (I had to make `force` public!), this won't work for the same reason:

```
int main() {
    auto x = &Alpha::force;
}
```

Resulting error is:

```
<source>:15:10: error: variable 'x' with type 'auto' has incompatible initializer of type '<overloaded function type>'
    auto x = &Alpha::force;
         ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

There is just no way to deduce the type from `&Alpha::force` alone.

---

You can pick one from the overload set via a `static_cast`:

```
auto x = static_cast< const Dummy& (Alpha::*)() const>(&Alpha::force);
```

Similar for the non-const:

```
auto y = static_cast< Dummy& (Alpha::*)()>(&Alpha::force);
```

---

PS: Your quote from the docs actually do not mention member functions. I suppose thats due to an incomplete quote. If `def` cannot accept member function pointers you would have to either make `force` static, or wrap the call in a free function / lambda. Don't forget that pointers to member functions are fundamentally different from pointers to free functions (they need an object to be called).